# Samba domain server worked - once

Tags: debian, authentication, samba

For reasons that would take a while to explain, I am trying to get a Samba AD domain controller working with a domain member which acts as a mail server; I am trying to get the mail server to authenticate to the domain, specifically so that my users can set their passwords in the domain and have that reflected to the mail server. I had set that up, and it worked; then circumstances left it idle for a month before I could bring it live, and now it no longer works. The AD DC is running Debian 4.19.0-18-amd64 and Samba Version 4.9.5-Debian; the supposed member mailserver is running Debian 11 (Linux 5.4.0) with Samba 4.13.17-Ubuntu.
DNS seems to resolve:

```
~$ nslookup -type=SRV _ldap._tcp.ghla.lan
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
_ldap._tcp.ghla.lan     service = 0 100 389 mainserver.ghla.lan.

Authoritative answers can be found from:

~$ nslookup mainserver.ghla.lan
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   mainserver.ghla.lan
Address: 10.2.1.200
```

However, I can't connect to the server:

```
$ wbinfo --ping-dc
checking the NETLOGON for domain[GHLA] dc connection to "" failed
failed to call wbcPingDc: WBC_ERR_DOMAIN_NOT_FOUND
```

And an attempt to rejoin the domain fails:

```
$ sudo net ads join -Uadministrator
Enter administrator's password:
Failed to join domain: failed to find DC for domain GHLA - The address handle that was given to the transport was invalid.
```

Can anyone give me any idea where to look? I can't immediately find any useful information on that error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid 'You must have 50 reputation to comment', so I will comment as an answer!

There is too much possibly wrong to sort it out here, one problem is that you are using an ancient version of Samba on the DC.

I suggest you go here:
https://lists.samba.org/mailman/listinfo/samba

Register for the samba mailing and come and talk to me there.

Comment: I'm going to tag this as the answer, even though I haven't yet got things working completely. The pointer to the version issue seems to have been gold, as updating Samba on the AD DC to current restored the ability to ping the server, join that domain, and log in as a domain user. If I'm unable to make the mail server behave, I'll hit the mailing list mentioned above.